mat-autocomplete not showing options Angular
I'm trying to implement material autocompleter in my Angular 8 application, but options are not being displayed.
As you can see, I've already tried applying z-index: 9999 as advised in Angular mat-autocomplete not showing options

And options are present in filteredData: Observable<string[]>;
HTML looks like this:
<div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-6 ">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width search-header-input">
        <input matInput [formControl]="myControl" placeholder="{{ 'search-text' | translate }}" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete style="z-index: 9999 !important; position: relative" autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredData | async" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

I'm logging the result of the API call used to fill filteredData and it does have it:
ngOnInit() {
        this.filteredData = this.strABuscar.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            tap(value => console.log('Input value:', value)),
            switchMap(value => this.customData ? this.customData.searchWithReturn(value) : []),
            tap(options => {
                console.log('Filtered options:', options);
                //this.cdr.detectChanges();
                this.cdr.markForCheck();
            })
        );
    }


I've also added a span and it seems like data is ok:
<span *ngFor="let item of filteredData | async">{{item}}

Can someone pinpoint the issue?
Thanks in advance

Cannot reproduce Demo. The <mat-option> is not showing possibly due to the filteredData observable is empty. Do you confirm that the filteredData observable has the array value? Try to print out in HTML to validate.

@YongShun I've edited the question adding what I think is relevant given your comment, if you are missing something else, let me know. Thanks!

Turns out that in order for it to work, you first need to add
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
to your styles.css and then if needed style the input over the default styles.

The autocomplete CSS does not apply to the dropdown since, it's rendered in the root of the application. So you need to add some custom CSS.
Try adding z-index to the overlay of autocomplete, then it might solve the issue.
You need to add this CSS to the global-styles.scss file, not at the component level:
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    z-index: 3000 !important; // give more if needed!
}

Another way to do this is to use [class]="custom-panel" property of autocomplete to add a class, then conditionally add the CSS only for a particular autocomplete:
    <mat-autocomplete [class]="custom-panel"  autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredData | async" [value]="item">
            {{ item }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

Then the CSS will be:
.panel-class .cdk-overlay-pane {
    z-index: 3000 !important; // give more if needed!
}


I dont have a global-styles.scss, as I'm working with css, but I added
.cdk-overlay-pane {
z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
to my stles.css with no luck, it's still not showing up

@StzEZ Then go to angular material autocomplete examples, see how the popup is added in HTML using inspect element. then compare how it differes from your HTML
